# Combine schema property types when defining a component

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm writing a component which can accept and array of vec3 as a schema property:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('control-arrows', {
    schema: {
        'directions': {
            'type': 'array',
            'default': [
                {'x':  1, 'y': 0, 'z':  0},
                {'x': -1, 'y': 0, 'z':  0},
                {'x':  0, 'y': 0, 'z':  1},
                {'x':  0, 'y': 0, 'z': -1}
            ]
        }
    },
    /* init and stuff */
}
```

As shown in the example, I used the type `array`. However, this type is not restrictive enough, as it should be an `array` of `vec3`. Note that the number of `vec3` can vary, and therefore I cannot use 4 properties with the `vec3` type.

How to enforce such a restriction? And more especially, how to correctly parse the HTML part which could be:

```
<a-entity
    control-arrows: "positions: 1 0 1, -1 0 -1">
</a-entity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom property type: https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/core/component.html#custom-property-type

```
schema: {
    'directions': {
        'parse': function (val) {
           return val.split(',').map(AFRAME.utils.coordinates.parse);
        },
        'default': [
            {'x':  1, 'y': 0, 'z':  0},
            {'x': -1, 'y': 0, 'z':  0},
            {'x':  0, 'y': 0, 'z':  1},
            {'x':  0, 'y': 0, 'z': -1}
        ]
    }
},
```